# How to Query Inside The Document in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, geojson

I am looking for a mongodb query finding the distance between two points within a document. My collection consists of taxi trips belonging to New York City obtained from [TLC](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml). The collection consists of trips like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa8d5b22d514514d4f95c08"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "geometry_pk" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.993896484375,
            40.7501106262207
        ]
    },
    "properties" : {
        "ID_Postgres" : 1,
        "VendorID" : 2,
        "passenger_count" : 1,
        "store_and_fwd_flag" : "N",
        "RatecodeID" : 1,
        "trip_distance" : 1.59,
        "payment_type" : 1,
        "fare_amount" : 12.0,
        "extra" : 1.0,
        "mta_tax" : 0.5,
        "tip_amount" : 3.25,
        "tolls_amount" : 0.0,
        "improvement_surcharge" : 0.3,
        "total_amount" : 17.05,
        "tpep_pickup_datetime" : ISODate("2015-01-15T19:05:39.000Z"),
        "tpep_dropoff_datetime" : ISODate("2015-01-15T19:23:42.000Z")
    },
    "geometry_do" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.9747848510742,
            40.750617980957
        ]
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa8d5b22d514514d4f95c09"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "geometry_pk" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -74.0016479492188,
            40.7242431640625
        ]
    },
    "properties" : {
        "ID_Postgres" : 2,
        "VendorID" : 1,
        "passenger_count" : 1,
        "store_and_fwd_flag" : "N",
        "RatecodeID" : 1,
        "trip_distance" : 3.3,
        "payment_type" : 1,
        "fare_amount" : 14.5,
        "extra" : 0.5,
        "mta_tax" : 0.5,
        "tip_amount" : 2.0,
        "tolls_amount" : 0.0,
        "improvement_surcharge" : 0.3,
        "total_amount" : 17.8,
        "tpep_pickup_datetime" : ISODate("2015-01-10T20:33:38.000Z"),
        "tpep_dropoff_datetime" : ISODate("2015-01-10T20:53:28.000Z")
    },
    "geometry_do" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.9944152832031,
            40.7591094970703
        ]
    }
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa8d5b22d514514d4f95c0a"),
    "type" : "Feature",
    "geometry_pk" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.9633407592773,
            40.8027877807617
        ]
    },
    "properties" : {
        "ID_Postgres" : 3,
        "VendorID" : 1,
        "passenger_count" : 1,
        "store_and_fwd_flag" : "N",
        "RatecodeID" : 1,
        "trip_distance" : 1.8,
        "payment_type" : 2,
        "fare_amount" : 9.5,
        "extra" : 0.5,
        "mta_tax" : 0.5,
        "tip_amount" : 0.0,
        "tolls_amount" : 0.0,
        "improvement_surcharge" : 0.3,
        "total_amount" : 10.8,
        "tpep_pickup_datetime" : ISODate("2015-01-10T20:33:38.000Z"),
        "tpep_dropoff_datetime" : ISODate("2015-01-10T20:43:41.000Z")
    },
    "geometry_do" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.9518203735352,
            40.8244132995605
        ]
    }
}
```

The pickup point is recorded under "geometry_pk" attribute and the dropoff point is recorded under "geometry_do".

I need to query distance between the pickup and dropoff points for each document (i.e. taxi trip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just query for your embedded coordinate fields and calculate distance after in your code :

```
db.collection.find({
    _id: your_id
}, {
    _id: 1,
    "geometry_pk.coordinate": 1,
    "geometry_do.coordinate": 1
});
```

Comment: How could I use the coordinates as variables?

Comment: for the ObjectID, check if it's not converted in string. And for your coordinate, use a callback function(err, result), the coordinate will be in result.geometry_pk.coordinate. Same for geometry_do

Comment: Thank you very much.
var a = db.nyc2015.find({
    _id: ObjectId("5aa8d5b22d514514d4f95c0e")
}, {
    _id: 1,
    "geometry_pk.coordinates": 1,
    "geometry_do.coordinates": 1
}).toArray();


print(a[0].geometry_pk.coordinates[0])   This code worked to take the coordinates into array but I don't know how to save 4 million records into array. In any case I can continue from here. Thank you so much.

Comment: don't forget to validate the response ;)

Comment: You can use the aggregation framework for that but you'll have an object that is composed of 4 millions objects, so i don't know if it's better in term of performance